# <=> operator overloading compare two vectors

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I am attempting to implement overloading for the <=> operator for my Vector class. I have defined the operator in the header file (.h), but when I try to implement it in the source file (.cpp), the header file is not aware of the implementation in the source file.
(I included `<compare>` in my .h file)

[image]

this is the operator overloading defined under public in my .h file:

```
auto operator<=>(const Vector& other) const;
```

and this is the implementation in the .cpp file:

```
auto Vector::operator<=>(const Vector& other) const
{
    if (m_size == other.m_size) {
        // Compare the contents of the vectors
        if (std::equal(m_vector, m_vector + m_size, other.m_vector)) {
            return std::strong_ordering::equal;
        }
    } else if (m_size < other.m_size) {
        return std::strong_ordering::less;
    }
    return std::strong_ordering::greater;
}
```

Comment: That's not a compiler error. It is just your IDE's code analysis having some trouble. Does the code actually fail to compile? In any case, please form a proper [mre] and include your compiler and/or IDE, depending on whether this turns out to be a compiler error or just an IDE diagnostic.

Comment: Also, you can't have the function return `auto` if you implement it in only one translation unit but want to use it in another one as well. The type must be deducible at every call site.

Comment: Try compiling the code.  Does it succeed?  Is there a compiler error?

Comment: I compiled successfully, it was the auto. thank you!

Comment: Also a quibble:   The overload of a function in your header file is a *declaration*, not a definition.    The "implementation" (your description) of that function is [compilation errors aside] the definition of that function.    The C++ standard is quite explicit on what is a declaration, and which declarations are definitions (since a definition is a type of declaration, but not all declarations are definitions) - use the words differently in discussing C++, and you'll often add unnecessary confusion.